# Guava - difference in intialCapacity and concurrencyLevel

Tags: java, guava

Guava docs says

https://guava.dev/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#initialCapacity(int)

> Sets the minimum total size for the internal hash tables. For example,
>   if the initial capacity is 60, and the concurrency level is 8, then
>   eight segments are created, each having a hash table of size eight.
>   Providing a large enough estimate at construction time avoids the need
>   for expensive resizing operations later, but setting this value
>   unnecessarily high wastes memory.

So what's the point of using `initialCapacity` if it's going to create 8 tables with 8 rows ? Is this some documentation typo?

Comment: Did you miss the **if** the initial capacity is 60? Changing concurrency level and initial capacity will affect the performance (and memory usage). The point of using `initialCapacity` is to avoid resizing when you put things in there.

Comment: @Kayaman        I didn't miss it - i think 8x8 doesn't become 60 magically. It's what MikeFHay explained in his answer that was missing in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, Guava's cache is implemented as multiple hash tables, each with a dedicated lock, so that concurrent writes don't all contest on a single lock.

`initialCapacity` refers to the capacity of the entire cache, not each individual underlying table. 8 tables each of size 8 can together handle up to 64 elements, so the documentation is correct.

Comment: 8x8=64, not 60. I guess my point here is that the documentation is not clear. It may be  correct. Thanks for your answer.